# Ruby Struct and OStruct: How can I require parameters

Tags: ruby

I want to validate that all parameters a Struct can have are always passed in when a new one is made.

Is there a baked in way or an elegant way to do something like...

```
MyStruct = Struct.new(:param1,:param2) do
  raise "params required" if param1.nil? || param2.nil?
end
```

The above code does not work of course, but I think it expresses what I want to move towards...

I want to see a list of all the parameters, too, in the error if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just handle it like a class

```
MyStruct = Struct.new(:param1, :param2, :param3) do |params|
  def initialize *args
    raise "params are required #{[:param1, :param2, :param3]} - #{args}}" unless (args.length == 3)
  end
end
str = MyStruct.new(1,2)
p str

# in `initialize': params are required [:param1, :param2, :param3] - [1, 2]} (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Just define your own constructor with explicit params count in the block:

```
MyStruct = Struct.new(:param1,:param2) do
  def initialize(param1, param2)
    super
  end
end

MyStruct.new('1','2') # => #<struct MyStruct param1="1", param2="2"> 
MyStruct.new('1') # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```